# Push button stop counting after pushing for a long period of time

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide

I have a project using arduino and its basic idea is to have one counter incremented by one single push button.
What I'm looking for is that once the push button is triggered for a long period of time not to make the counter1 for example incremented by one.

So how can I accomplish this task using Arduino's software?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: You could use an interrupt pin with positve edge. You should use a capacitor parallel to the button to debounce.

Comment: @NeverToLow and how could i accomplish that with the arduino software?!

Comment: Use a bigger type for the counter to prevent overflow. Or is the question about debouncing button presses?

Comment: @NeverToLow ok just one more thing
What should be the value of the capacitor that i should be using it in my circuit?

Comment: @user9428725 edited my answer so that a value I used is in there. Take for example a ceramics capacitor. They are avaiable leaded or in smd.

Comment: @NeverToLow ok i will apply what you have told me to solve the problem
Thank you soo much

Comment: What do you mean by "not to make the counter ... incremented"? Is it incremented repeatedly while pressing only once and you only want to increment once per press? Do you want to not increment at all (like an undo at change of users mind)? Do you poll the button or is this event triggered? What restricts you to that way?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use an interrupt pin with positve edge. You should use a capacitor parallel to the button to debounce.
Here is the reference page of arduino for external interrupts. 
[External Interrupts in Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/).

I think it's good described with some code examples. If you have questions on it let me know. The table at the top is important. Not all pins can be used for it.

So everytime you push the button the interrupt is triggered (if chosing option HIGH). If you hold the button no interrupt is triggered. In Interrupt Service Routine you increment the counter.

For debouncing the button you can use e.g. a 100 nF ceramics capacitor (e.g. 10V). But Debouncing can be done several ways. Here is the question with good answers on debouncing switches used with arduino. [Switch debouncing - would toggle switch still bounce](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/41674/switch-debouncing-would-toggle-switch-still-bounce). There is also an ISR given which should work good. You don't need a hardware debouncing anymore using it.